# JSONObject text must begin with '{' error

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to get the value of "name" from the following body:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ENTITY_CHANNELS",
    "description": "The list of channels use to deliver through.",
    "metadata": "{}"
  },
  {
    "name": "INTAKE_SFTP",
    "description": null,
    "metadata": "{\n  \"fields\":[\n    {\n      
\"field_name\":\"user_uat\",\n      \"field_type\":\"string\",\n      
\"field_required\":true, \n\t  \"field_description\": \"UAT User name\"\n    
},\n    {\n      \"field_name\":\"user_prod\",\n      
\"field_type\":\"string\",\n      \"field_required\":false, \n\t  
\"field_description\": \"Production User name\"\n    },\n    {\n      
\"field_name\":\"folder\",\n      \"field_type\":\"string\",\n      
\"field_required\":true, \n\t  \"field_description\": \"Folder\"\n    },\n    
{\n      \"field_name\":\"address_UAT\",\n      \"field_type\":\"string\",\n      
\"field_required\":true, \n\t  \"field_description\": \"UAT address\"\n    
},\n    {\n      \"field_name\":\"address_PROD\",\n      
\"field_type\":\"string\",\n      \"field_required\":false, \n\t  
\"field_description\": \"Production address\"\n    },\n    {\n      
\"field_name\":\"port\",\n      \"field_type\":\"integer\",\n      
\"field_required\":true, \n\t  \"field_description\": \"Port\"\n    },\n    
{\n      \"field_name\":\"protocol_version\",\n      
\"field_type\":\"version\",\n      \"field_required\":false, \n\t  
\"field_description\": \"Protocol version\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"
  }
]
```

I've tried the following code:

```
String settingsTypeData = response.body().toString();
JSONObject settingsTypeObject = new JSONObject(settingsTypeData);
Assert.assertEquals(settingsTypeObject.get("name"), "ENTITY_CHANNELS");
```

But I keep on getting the error: JSONObject text must begin with '{' error. I would like to extract the value of "name". Can someone help me?

Comment: Since the outer brackets are square, perhaps you should be using JSONArray, not JSONObject. Or you could remove the outer [].

Comment: Your input is a JSONArray that contains two JSONObjects

Comment: As already pointed out: you're trying to parse an _array_ as an _object_ and hence the parser complains. So you'd best do what Henry suggests and parse the array as an array (i.e. JSONArray) and then operate on the elements of that array.

Comment: JSON is not valid. try using some JSON validator.

Comment: @MehrajMalik: I suspect it's just an artifact of pasting it into the question, but yes, H.Avram - If we copy and paste that JSON into a validator, it fails. You seem to have combined actual JSON with a string representation of it complete with `\n` and `\t`.

Comment: @Henry I just checked it http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ here, and it is saying JSON is not valid.

Comment: `JSON.parse(...)` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 204`

Comment: The nested JSON string you typed up there has newlines in it. Did you embed them as you pasted it into the question? Kind of worthless if you did, if you didn't, that's your error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I realized what was my mistake. I used:

```
String settingsTypeData = response.body().toString();
```

The below code will solve my problem:

```
String settingsTypeData = response.body().string();
    JSONArray settingsTypeArray = new JSONArray(settingsTypeData);

    String firstSettingType = settingsTypeArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
    Assert.assertEquals(firstSettingType, "ENTITY_CHANNELS");

    String secondSettingType = settingsTypeArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("name");
    Assert.assertEquals(secondSettingType, "INTAKE_SFTP");
```

Answer (score -1):

use JSONArray instead of JSONObject,
because the above whole-json is the JSONArray.
Then iterate this JSONArray and fetch name from each JSONObject

```
   String settingsTypeData = response.body().toString();
   try {
        JSONArray settingsTypeArray = new JSONArray(settingsTypeData);
        for(int i=0;i<settingsTypeArray.length();i++){
            String name = settingsTypeArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: name = "+name);
        }
    } catch (JSONException jex){
        jex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: JSON itself is not valid, what change is it gonna make?

Comment: thanku @mehraj malik yes json is invalid... what i see is that at the json creation time the value of metadata is stringify & push to metadata field.. which is wrong & hence this all happens...also i think this may be the valid json &  the escape sequence is been added by compiler or debugger which is printed this way on IDE console.